# Installing mono without root privileges

Tags: linux, .net-framework, c#, mono-framework

I use mono on my mac now for my .NET development, when I dont feel like using my pc, but I want to use mono on my Universities linux server, but I dont have root. Is there a way I can install mono in my local directory, and have people I submit my work to compile and run my programs?

Comment: What does "and have people I submit my work to compile and run my programs" mean?

Comment: I'm not sure this will apply to mono, but you can use "chroot" to run programs inside a fake root file system within your home directory.

Comment: we have to submit our work using a submit utility and provide a makefile, I would like them to be able to run my programs even if they do not have mono themselves.

Comment: @user1765444 - Yes, Mono can compile to a standalone file.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411333/standalone-executables-with-mono-on-linux)